# file_get_contents for Coral CDN using own context resource won't work

Tags: php, http, proxy, cdn

I'm trying to load URLs using [Coral CDN](http://www.coralcdn.org/) but I could not make it work if I use my own context resource.

```
<?php
$url = 'http://www.stackoverflow.com/';
echo substr(htmlentities(file_get_contents($url)),0,100); // works OK

echo '<hr />';

$url = 'http://www.stackoverflow.com.nyud.net/'; // CORAL content distribution network
echo substr(htmlentities(file_get_contents($url)),0,100); // works OK

echo '<hr />';

$options = array(
      'http'=>array(
        'method'=>"POST",
        'header'=>
            "Host: www.stackoverflow.com.nyud.net\r\n".
            "Connection: keep-alive\r\n".
            "Content-Length: 3\r\n".
            "Cache-Control: max-age=0\r\n".
            "Origin: http://www.stackoverflow.com.nyud.net\r\n".
            "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/21.0.1180.89 Safari/537.1\r\n".
            "Content-Type: application/x-www-url-form-encoded\r\n".
            "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8\r\n".
            "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch\r\n".
            "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8\r\n".
            "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3",
         'content'=>'a=1'
    ));
$context = stream_context_create($options);
echo file_get_contents($url,false,$context); // 405 error?
?>
```

This is the actual error I get:

> **Warning**: file_get_contents(http://www.stackoverflow.com.nyud.net/) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 405 in **C:\...\lab\php-exec\index.php(4) : eval()'d code** on line **29**

I know [curl](http://www.php.net/curl) might work but I insist to use [file_get_contents()](http://www.php.net/file_get_contents), how do you think can I solve this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I think you just **can't** send a POST request to `*.nyud.net` website, see a [basic post](http://hurl.eu/hurls/d28d4dfecd59d672b1bc150b324f337dceb73995/b2293f58f42d54676ce28cdfdae53bdd58804bd3).

Request:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: www.stackoverflow.com.nyud.net
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 3
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

a=1
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.0 405
date: Thu, 04 Oct 2012 21:53:32 GMT
server: CoralWebPrx/0.1.20 (See http://coralcdn.org/)
content-type: text/html
connection: close
```

Which seems to be normal because it acts as a CDN for **any** website, no mater if the website is ok or not.

Since a POST request means you want to submit something to the website, to create, update, or what ever, CoralCDN can't handle it because it can't submit something to an other website on **its behalf**. It could be a security issue. Nobody can POST what ever they want to a website anonymously...

If you want to send a parameter to the request, put them in the url (GET request are OK) but there won't be any solution to send a POST request to CoralCDN, even using cURL.

Answer (score 0):

Error 405 means " This request method is not allow ."

You can change the request method from POST to GET . It may works.

```
<?php
$url = 'http://www.stackoverflow.com.nyud.net/';
$options = array(
        'http'=>array(
        'method'=>"GET",
        'header'=>"Accept-language: en\r\n"
  )
);

$context = stream_context_create($options);
echo file_get_contents($url,false,$context); //works
```

Comment: but then `$_POST['a']` is not being set